# Usage of relative=up in selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

Can any one explain me the usage of

```
selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");
```

sample code:

```
    selenium.selectFrame("frame");
    String Error_MSG_1 = selenium.getText("//div");
    selenium.selectFrame("relative=up");    -----> here if I remove this   
                                                statement it throws an exceptions
    if (selenium.isTextPresent("error message")) {
        assertEquals("","");
    }
    //Close error pop-up
    selenium.click(Close_popup);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your web applications implement iframes, often times, while testing, say, a text string, you can clearly see it being displayed in the browser, but upon playback, the selenium script may fail. This is because the script may not be placing the right iframe into context. `selenium.selectFrame(...)` is used to set the right frame in which the assertion/verification is to be performed.

Specifically, `selenium.selectFrame(“relative=up”)` is used to move one iFrame up a level. In a related manner, you can use `selenium.selectFrame(“relative=top”)` to select the top level iFrame.